# Как использовать AutoValue?

Tags: android, retrofit, pojo

Пытаюсь перевести проект на Retrofit 2. Хочу создать Pojo с помощью `@AutoValue`.

В **build.gradle** добавил

```
compileOnly "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5"
annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5"
```

Создаю **POJO** по [примеру с гитхаба](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md)

```
import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;

import java.util.Date;

@AutoValue
public abstract class Person {

    public static Person create(String email, String password) {
        return new AutoValue_Person(email, password);
    }

    public abstract String email();

    public abstract String password();

    public abstract String lastName();

    public abstract String firstName();

    public abstract String middleName();

    public abstract Date birthday();
}
```

Естественно, `AutoValue_Person` горит красным, такого класса нет. Не понимаю, откуда он в примере взялся.

**Вопрос решен**, необходимо было пересобрать проект. После этого ошибка исчезает.